# C# TCP Unit Tests SocketException can't run all tests

Tags: c#, sockets, unit-testing, tcp

I have a rather bizarre problem.  I have some unit tests to are designed to test exceptions thrown in some TCP communication I am working on.  Individually, all of the tests work.  However, if I try and run them in sequence, the first one passed and all of the remaining tests fail.  I am not sure why this is happening.  I am creating a new socket in my [TestInitialize] each time.  I thought maybe the listener was just hanging, so I set a wait at the start of test 2 of 10 seconds and it still fails.  BUT, when I run test one and then test two back to back (about 1 second apart) individually, everything works.

Any idea what might be causing this?  My hunch is that the listen port is cleared when the overall test finishes, so I can't rebind a new socket to that port when I run them in sequence.

"Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted"

Comment: Some code helps the readers. Help us to help you. But a "hunch" will be to close the socket on clean up? Or if you can, use a different port.

Comment: I would speculate from the error that you might not be closing the socket once the test is complete. However, please add some code so that can better analyse.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the mistake.  I had been making the socket and binding it under the TestInitialize attribute.  What I needed to do was make the socket under the ClassInitialize attribute so it is always there.  Then I just open my reading threads in my TestInitialize area.